# I am trying to convert a string list to intger but i get the error below

Tags: python

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
print(student_heights)

student_heights = list(map(float, student_heights))
print(student_heights)
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

for i in student_heights:
  total = student_heights + i

for student in student_heights:
  num = student + 1

avg = total/num
```

```
Input a list of student heights 5,6,73
['5,6,73']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    student_heights = list(map(float, student_heights))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5,6,73'
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: You have to split the input

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're inputting a list of *comma-separated* values. But `str.split()` (with no arguments) splits on whitespace. So, pass `","` as an argument to `split` to split on commas.

Rather than `map`ping your values to `float` and then casting to `int` in a `for` loop, `map` directly to `int`.

Rather than calculating the `total` and `num` in `for` loops, use `sum` and `len`.

(Worth noting: your code for calculating `num`, if you expect it to calculate how many students there are, is incorrect. Can you figure out why?)

For example:

```py
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split(",")
student_heights = list(map(int, student_heights))

total, num = sum(student_heights), len(student_heights)
avg = total/num
```

*Post-script: which student is '73' tall?*

Comment: thanks. this worked